# What filters are actively influencing my data tables in Spofire?

Tags: spotfire

Is there any way to see what filters are currently active and influencing your data table?  For example, if there is data that is being limited and I want to figure out which filter might be limiting my data without resetting all the filters within that Filter Scheme.

Comment: I should add, this questions was for version 6.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to see filters, open the Filters panel. at the bottom is a pane showing which filters are enabled for the current filter set. this is only available from, I believe, Spotfire 7 and up.

to show Data Limiting, you can enable an option in the visualization settings to show text like "Data limited by: Expression"

Comment: I just got v7 and now i see it there.  Very simple to find now.

Answer (score 1):

Type `status:m` in the filter selection field, that will show you all the columns where filtering is applied (only if that field is enabled in actual page's filtering scheme!).

Besides that have a look also on **Data limiting** to see whether selection in any other visualization effects your filtering.